# How to display search results within the same Panels page

Tags: panels

I have front page with exposed filters and search results block on it within panels. In my case search results are displayed on a map. When i specify something in filters  and push "Search", i'm directed on search results page that has no panels and has path of front page's view. I want search results to stay within same panels as before i push "Search". How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use *Content pane* with Views? If so, under **Pane settings** make sure `Use Panel path: Yes`.

Comment: sounded goog but it didn't work. Still wondering where the problem is.

Comment: Solved. Changed value of views/edit/advanced/Exposed form in block:from Yes to No